# How shorten Kotlin StateFlow code with Generics?

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have this:

```
val navigateToMainFragmentEvent: StateFlow<State<Event<Boolean>>>

 if (navigateToMainFragmentEvent.collectAsState().value is State.TriggerState) {
        (viewModel.navigateToMainFragmentEvent.collectAsState().value
                as State.TriggerState).data.getContentIfNotHandled()
            ?.let {
                if (it) {
                    Timber.tag("Nurs").d("collect as state ")
                    navController.popBackStack()
                    navController.navigate(MAIN_SCRENN)
                }
            }
    }
```

is it possible to shorten with generics the `if` statement?

Comment: Can you show the State class? And what is `collectAsState`?

Answer (score 1):

```
val state = navigateToMainFragmentEvent.value
if (state is State.TriggerState) {
     state.data.getContentIfNotHandled()?.let {
         // do sth
     }
}
```

As an advice: You can define `ifNotHandled` method with a lambda argument in your Event class to more shortening:

```
    fun ifNotHandled(callback: () -> T) {
        if (!hasBeenHandled) {
            hasBeenHandled = true
            callback.invoke(content)
        }
    }




  val state = navigateToMainFragmentEvent.value
  if (state is State.TriggerState) {
         state.data.ifNotHandled {
            // do sth
         }
    }
```